# Configuración vs code por defecto al trabajar y/o practicar javascript

Tags: javascript, web, plugin, vscode, web.config

En aras de retomar javascript estudiar retomando lo que se y para aprender las nuevas características de este, me tope con algo un poco confuso para mí, quizás sea algo normal para el que ya tiene rato.

Uso VS CODE para trabajar programación web, y al crear un repositorio, luego crear una carpeta y posterior el primer archivo, pero cuando hice esos pasos, me salio de manera inmediato el siguiente mensaje:

```
[Info  - 9:34:56 p. m.] ESLint server stopped.
[Info  - 9:35:02 p. m.] ESLint server running in node v12.4.0
[Info  - 9:35:02 p. m.] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 9:35:41 p. m.] 
Failed to load the ESLint library for the document c:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\Retaking-Js\array functions\array_functions.js

To use ESLint please install eslint by running npm install eslint in the workspace folder Retaking-Js
or globally using 'npm install -g eslint'. You need to reopen the workspace after installing eslint.

If you are using yarn or pnpm instead of npm set the setting `eslint.packageManager` to either `yarn` or `pnpm`
Alternatively you can disable ESLint for the workspace folder Retaking-Js by executing the 'Disable ESLint' command.
[Info  - 9:38:36 p. m.] ESLint library loaded from: c:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\Retaking-Js\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
[Warn  - 9:38:36 p. m.] 
No ESLint configuration (e.g .eslintrc) found for file: c:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\Retaking-Js\array functions\array_functions.js
File will not be validated. Consider running 'eslint --init' in the workspace folder Retaking-Js
Alternatively you can disable ESLint by executing the 'Disable ESLint' command.
```

Luego pues instale **eslint** de forma local usando el siguiente comando

`npm i eslint`

La instalación no tuvo ningún problema, creando una carpeta con unos ficheros, uno de `.gitignore` y `package-lock.json`

[image: imagen_estudio]

Existe algún tipo de comando para ejecutar antes de crear cualquier fichero y que este nos cree una especie de configuración rápida para evitar mensajes de alertas futuros. Claro cualquier otra recomendación o tip que tengan para soportar las características nuevas de Js que sea de manera facil.

Comment: Te refieres al archivo [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/)?

Comment: No se si sea eso, pero sé que tiene que ver con configuración, ese mensaje me salio de forma instantánea, como si se necesitara una configuracion por defecto para javascript.

Comment: cada proyecto tiene un archivo .editorconf este te ayuda a muchas cosas, es la configuración del editor para tu proyecto, ahora si quieres que tu IDE tenga una configuración deseada debes acceder a tu IDE preferido y modificarla

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es que instales de manera global eslint, para que de esta manera evites este tipo de mensajes en el futuro.

Para inicializar un proyecto con node.js, se recomienza ingresar el siguiente comando:

```sh
node init
```

Ya que este te ayudará a generar el `package.json` con la configuración mínima necesaria para comenzar a trabajar.

Comment: interesante, no importa si no es Node lo que trabajare, si no solo practicar Js en el front, recomiendas usar ese mismo comando?

Comment: Si es únicamente frontend, no es necesario utilizarlo, lo único que si te recomiendo es instalar es ```eslint``` de manera **global** para evitar posibles mensajes de advertencia en el futuro de VS Code.